# Does JavaScript Number.toString method lose accuracy after a threshold?

Tags: javascript, tostring, parseint

The output of the following:

```js
let x = 10**23;
console.log(x.toString(16))
```

comes out `152d02c7e14af6000000` which actually computes to `99999999999999991611392` and not `10**23`. Interestingly enough, the following doesn't compute to `false`:

```js
let x = 10**23;
console.log(x==parseInt(x.toString(16),16))
```

Am I getting something wrong here?

Comment: Javascript maximum safe integer is 2^53-1, which is lower than 10^23.

Comment: @Justinas yes, using BigInt gives me the correct hex representation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript numbers are floating point, which lose precision the larger they get. When you exceed [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) (which is 2<sup>53</sup> – 1), the precision becomes >1.

This also means that things like `10**23 === (1**23 - 123)` evaluates to `true`.